# MySQL Database won't start in XAMPP Manager-osx

Tags: php, mysql, macos, xampp

I downloaded XAMPP about a month ago and it was working just fine. Today I installed a voice recognition software and then restarted my computer. Ever since, MySQL won't start in my manager-osx application. It doesn't throw me an in the application log. This is what it says:

```
Stopping all servers...
Stopping Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd stopped
Stopping ProFTPD...
Checking syntax of configuration file
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd stopped
Restarting all servers...
Starting MySQL Database...

Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting ProFTPD...
Checking syntax of configuration file
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd started
```

Both my ProFTPD and my Apache Web Server are running. MySQL isn't.
When I go to phpmyadmin, it throws me this error message.

```
#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

Please help me. I have no idea what to do.

UPDATE:

After looking around the internet a bit, I found a similar problem a user had with MAMP, another user recommended killing the mysql process, what ever that means. Could this be a fix to my problem?

UPDATE 2:

I found the answer to my problem but I can't answer it yet. So here's the answer:

1) Open terminal and type

```
sudo su
```

and then put in  your password

2) Then type

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

(just copy and paste this)

3) You will need to get the process id of mysql. There should be number near the top, something like 739 or 8827

4) Kill the process using

```
kill -9 {process id}
```

this should look something like this: kill -9 739

5) Restart MySQL in manager-osx

Comment: When did the problem start?

Comment: You can also go to activity monitor in the utilities folder and kill the process there.

Comment: I would also recommend backing up your web directory folder and re-install xampp..  That works for me.

Comment: What do you think *caused* the problem?

Comment: I have installed another mysql into my mac. I stopped that one then it solved.

Comment: In case my id is none of the above, you didn't share which column that contains the actual id? Is it the first one 4401? Or the fifth one 688?

Answer (score 188):

This should work:
`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`

Comment: This works when manager-osx can't start the mySQL database on your localhost

Comment: Awesome, this works! Am curious, though, why the manager-osx start mySQL, and if I'll have to sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start ? Or can the manager-osx script be corrected?

Comment: Didn't work for me: 

`Starting MySQL
..................................................................................................... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/gmac.local.pid).`

Comment: @GeoffreyHale and everyone else facing this problem: look at your log (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/YOURNAME.err) and probably you'll discover what caused the error.
Mine was `[ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ibdata1, error: 35` and furthermore `[Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.`
Heck! It was right! Kill the mysqld process, type benshittu's command and it should work.

Comment: This did not work for me. What version of XAMPP are you using when you do that? I'm on 1.8.3-4 for compatibility reasons for an application.

Comment: Not working. Keeps giving me an error. No message. Just "Error!"

Comment: what to do if we get error in terminal as:  7548 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
 ERROR!

Comment: Thanks
This really worked for me on XAMPP version 7.3.19

Comment: Be sure to check out @Geoffreey Hale 's post below for the { sudo killall mysqld }

Answer (score 145):

## Minimal Guide

1.
`sudo killall mysqld`

2.
manager-osx > start mysql

---

### If that didn't work...

`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`

*Google the error...*

---

### Examples:

**Error:**

`ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/<computername>.local.pid)`

**My Solution:**

In `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf` change `user = <uid>` s that `<uid>` is `uid` from `id` command.

```
$ id
uid=...

$ vim /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf
...
```

Comment: Absolutely helped me. Thanks.

Comment: seems like "sudo killall mysqld" is not catching all running mysql instances. i had mysql running with homebrew so check "brew services" and if the mysql process is running there stop it with "brew services stop mysql"

Comment: Every now and then have to do this in order to use MySQL in macos xampp.

Answer (score 100):

If these commands don't work for you:

```
sudo killall mysqld
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

Try this:

For XAMPP 7.1.1-0, I changed the port number from 3306 to 3307.

1. Click on *Manage Servers*
2. Select *MySQL Database*
3. Click on *Configure* on your right
4. Change your port number to 3307
5. Click OK
6. Close your Control Panel and relaunch it.

You are now good to go.

Comment: I treid changing the port and restarting the manager worked for me.Thank you.

Comment: Perfect man, I changed port number from 3306 to 3307. Thank you !

Comment: I have trying same thing but not working for new xampp 7.2.2:

Following error message received (I have question blocked so I can't ask as new question on stackoverflow)

`Starting MySQL
.2018-03-06 11:21:32 3610 mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/Bharats-iMac.local.err'.
2018-03-06 11:21:32 3610 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
 ERROR!`

Comment: I run this command sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
it's working for me.

Comment: Changing the port of XAMPP MySQL to 3307 works fine!

Comment: Worked the Changing port number to 3307

Comment: HA! Changing the port number worked for me. thanks! :fire:

Comment: MySQL was not starting for me. Changed port from 3306 to 3307 and it does the job.

Answer (score 33):

check the err log on your /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ with filename like your_machine_name.local.err, if you find something like:  "Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace ... uses space ID"

the following works for me:

edit file:

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf

find the [mysqld] section, add one line:

innodb_force_recovery = 1

then run

sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server start

everything is ok again.

and then the last step:

edit the my.cnf again and remove the line you just added :

innodb_force_recovery = 1

and restart mysql again. Otherwise all your tables will be read only

Answer (score 31):

Try running these two commands in the terminal:

1. `sudo killall mysqld`
2. `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`

Answer (score 13):

For me the following worked: Change permission into 'read only' for 'everyone' to the file `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf`. Then start MySQL from XAMPP manager.

Comment: Worked for me! Perfect!

Comment: so does that mean you do `chmod 444 my.cnf` in terminal?

Answer (score 7):

1. close XAMPP control
2. sudo killall mysqld
3. sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start

Comment: Worked for me! – Don't worry if `sudo killall mysqld` throws something like `process not found`.

Answer (score 7):

it happened to me. and

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

not work for me.

> so, i reinstall the xampp, then fix it.

attention:

> **reinstall the xampp,  will not delete mysql data, no need to worry about that.**

Comment: Instead for me, this code-line works every time when MySQL doesn't start

Comment: Reinstall XAMPP gives me a bigger problem. Can't access the table data anymore

Answer (score 6):

I first couldn't manage to kill mysql daemon with the commands posted here. So I remembered my linux times and did the following:

I monitored the running processes by running `top` in one terminal window. Then I killed mysqld via `sudo killall mysqld` (screw the PID ;-) ) in another and restarted via `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`.

Answer (score 4):

What I did was the following: In XAMPP Control Panel I edited the my.ini file of configuration of MySql and changed the port from 3306 to 3307 and it worked, hope it helped!

Edit: after you save this changes be sure that the service is off and then restart the service. I had this same problem when I installed MySQL, it's just the port.

Answer (score 4):

There's been a lot of answer, but I think I found what is causing it, at least for me. It looks like if you put your computer to sleep (or it falls asleep on its own), when it reopens, it tries to open the the mysql process again. At one point I looked at my activity monitor and I had 5 instances running - killing all of them and then starting mysql works.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

This worked for me.

Comment: ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/testingAccounts-Mac.local.pid)..  what to do

Comment: @iKrutarth look at my comment at benshittu's answer, maybe it'd be helpful also for you

Comment: Duplicate answer. An [older version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25481884/4137828) of this answer already exists.

Answer (score 4):

I had success with easy killing all active mysql processes in Monitor Activity tool:

1) close XAMPP control

2) open Monitor Activity

3) select filter for All processes (default is My processes)

4) search for: mysql

5) force quit all the mysql

6) relaunch XAMPP control and launch apache again

Enjoy

Answer (score 4):

try these two line from terminal

1. `sudo killall mysqld`
2. `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`

Answer (score 4):

on

> macOs High Sierra

if mysql is not getting started from manager- oxs and have tried direct command i.e

`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server start`

too than 
go to path edit

> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/

find file :

> my.cnf

edit it

under the [mysqld] section, add following line:

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

after it save and  run or can be done from manager-osx

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server start
```

it should start the mysql.

once its run you need to again
edit the

> my.cnf

file and remove the line just added

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

stop and start mysql again. by command

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server start
```

or 
by manager-osx

it will be working fine.

Answer (score 3):

It can cause because of the software you installed or may be any other software which is using the same port 3306. This 3306 port is used by the Mysql in XAMPP. Similar kind of problem I faced for Apache. I was running skype and trying to run the XAMPP but the skype uses the same port as Apache so it was not working. Then I sign out from skype then the port was free and the apache started. So you should look for the software in you laptop which is blocking or making busy this port. Free that port by closing the software and then run XAMPP and It will work.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem just now. I checked log file and found it is caused by the server was not shutdown correctly. So I found this http://rivenlinux.info/how-to-recover-innodb-corruption-for-mysql/ and add a simple configuration "innodb_force_recovery = 1" in [mysqld] in my.cnf. Then the problem was solved.

The log file is located /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql and it named accroding to your server name. Just link this XXX-MacBook-Pro.local.err

Comment: Thnx. This helped a lot. Found the error log and saw innodb was causing the problem. It now restarts, but now can't access the databases anymore. So there is bigger underlying problem :(. I think it has something to do with updating Mac OSX. This is not the first time. Only reinstalling xampp won't fix it either. The databases are corrupt....

Comment: For me it happened for that, the server was not shutdown correctly, but your solution didn't work. Only reinstall works.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers stated above in relation to changing the port number are in this situation the best way to solve this problem since you need your voice recognition software to coexist with MAMP. However, you must remember that changing this port number is going to affect all you subsequent connections to MySQL (i.e, terminal,php code,phpmyadmin,etc). Hence It would be advisable to change the port on which the voice recognition software runs. Hope this was helpful.

:)

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting this error

```
.............ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
```

**Try this**

Go to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/

if there is no file with the name **Your_Username.local.pid**

*`Your_Username should replace with your Mac Username`*

Create a file with this name

**Then try**

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

its worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It had the same problem, all I did was give read-only permissions for **ALL users (system included)** and all items included in the following folders:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin
```

and relaunch XAMPP control and launch mysql server again
or

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and get this error in hostname.err in directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql

> 2016-09-06 15:32:45 140735322399488 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is
>   disabled. 2016-09-06 15:32:45 140735322399488 [Note] Heuristic crash
>   recovery mode 2016-09-06 15:32:45 140735322399488 [Note] Please
>   restart mysqld without --tc-heuristic-recover 2016-09-06 15:32:45
>   140735322399488 [ERROR] Can't init tc log 2016-09-06 15:32:45
>   140735322399488 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 2016-09-06 15:32:48 20004 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/hostname.pid ended

Then I removed tc.log and It works fine after restart mysql through manager-osx

Comment: removing tc.log fixed this problem for me

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the fact that another instance of mysqd is already running in your mac-book-pro (MacOs-10). It's next to impossible to kill/pkill mysqld or   ....I tried that route many times, with out any success. Finally the following worked for me :

```
launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

wait a few minutes and check with

```
ps -ef|grep mysqld
```

It should be gone!

Answer (score 0):

It might be the possibility that your voice recognition software has a installer of mysql internally and when u installed this software, it has installed mysql too and added it to the service and this mysql service starts once your system starts. So now u r having two mysql servers (one from voice recognition software and second is from XAMPP) that's why killing the previous process (mysql service)  solved your problem. But this is not a permanent solution, you have to repeat it every time when ever you start your machine. So better is to find out that mysql server (service) and change its port no. OR change settings so that mysql service should not start when your machine start (but might be your voice recognition software won't work properly)

I hope it will help you.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have found a work-around by killing the process, but make sure you check for free space on your MySQL partition. If your logs or db files are consuming all your drive space, mysqld will not start.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the computer, or using the 'kill' commands listed above solve the problem. AS for preventing it from happening, I've found this occurring anytime my computer goes to sleep. The port is obviously kept reserved, and then on wake, mysql tries to reconnect to that port, but can't. This could be your problem also.

Answer (score 0):

I am running XAMPP 5.6.3-0 for OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 and ran into the same issue twice, the first time was with Mavericks. With a bunch of different solutions to the issue with MySQL Database not starting using Manager App I wanted to confirm what had worked for me. The workaround that always worked and forced MySQL to start was by opening Terminal and using: 
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start 
I had the Manager App open and started ProFTPD and Apache and then ran the sudo command.

The other suggestion by wishap that worked was to locate /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf file and change the permissions for "everyone" to Read only.

The other problem I had that seems to be another issue with many solutions is the problem after everything is started then entering localhost which brings me to the xampp splash screen and then nothing. The only thing that worked for me, to at the very least, to access the phpMyAdmin page is by entering localhost/phpmyadmin

I hope this helps others reading through a bunch of threads for an answer.

Regards, 
Erik

Answer (score 0):

Try this, *sudo service mysql stop* it will stop any other mysql services and then restart xampp

Answer (score 0):

Just Click on Managed Servers Tab in XAMPP MANAGER , Now select MySQL Database, Click on configure on right side.

Change port from 3306 to 3307 and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It had the same problem, all I did was give read-only permissions for all users and all items included in the following folders:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometime there is just `ERROR!` message is shown in mysql comment on terminal. 
Then, just reinstall (overwrite) XAMPP, then it can be solved.

Comment: I also had just ERROR! and nothing else. I went with this thread, and then did the sudo killall steps. I didn't have to reinstall - osx el capitan

Answer (score 0):

maybe table innodb error after u reinstal or copy file db try to repair tbl innodb, if table cant be repair try delete db or table

xamppfiles/var/mysql/your db

or

xamppfiles/var/mysql/your db/your table

change permission folder to open folder database

before delete backup ur folder database

Answer (score 0):

After trying all possible options, the below trick worked for me:

1. Navigate to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ and open the files my.conf
2. Search for

   "# The MySQL server"

   [mysqld]

   user = mysql

   port=3308

and change the port number.

3. Start the mysql database again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MacOs:

`brew services list` to see all running services. if you have a mysql service currently running you will need to stop it with:

`brew services stop mysql`

Then try starting the mysql database in XAMPP again.

This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

It's because of the firewall settings.

1. Go to system preferences->Security and Privacy
2. Click on Firewall-> Firewall Options
3. If you have **Block all incoming connections** checked then uncheck it
4. Check **automatically allow signed software to receive incoming connections**, hit the lock save your settings
5. Open up xampp, go to manage servers, hit start all, and you will be prompted to accept or deny the incoming connection of mysql and ProFTPD. 
   6.Accept the connection

Answer (score -1):

On Mac, I checked the mysql error log file at:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/MyPCName.local.err
```

There I found

```
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./some_db_name/some_table_name.ibd
```

After I deleted that .ibd file and then started MySql, it started.

Answer (score -1):

Check the "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql" file's owner.

If you see different user and group instead of "_mysql".

> sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql mysql