# MySQL doesn't start in xampp in mac osx

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm on Max OS X Yosemite and have installed fresh version of XAMPP.

However, MySQL doesn't seem to start.
I've already looked in the `'/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp'` file and looks like `'unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'` is already there.

followed this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267064/mysql-database-wont-start-in-xampp-manager-osx) and killed the Mysql process but it also doesn't seem to work

When I execute this command 
        `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`

It throws an error
 `"Starting MySQL
... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/MacBook-Pro.local.pid)."`

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For me help this fix.

Step 1: Go to your Finder and edit the file as the following path below.

`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf`

Step 2: Open the file and find the [mysqld] section

add one line as following

`innodb_force_recovery = 1`

,and save.

Step 3: Run command in your Terminal

`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server start`

Wait until everything is OK.

Step 4: Edit the my.cnf again and remove the line you just added

`innodb_force_recovery = 1`

,and save.

Step 5: Stop for restart

`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server stop`

Wait until everything is OK.

Answer (score -2):

Hello I 'm using Mac OS X as well, once used XAMPP but also gave me errors sometimes , I recommend MAMP has not given me any problems ever and is easy to deploy.

Comment: Hi there, I just changed the port from 3306 to 3307 and it fixed the issue.

Comment: so perfect but if you want you can test the MAMP server