# what to do when mysql stopped working in xampp?

Tags: macos, web-services, xampp

this question is duplicate

[MySQL Database won't start in XAMPP Manager-osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267064/mysql-database-wont-start-in-xampp-manager-osx)

When I try to connect sql server from terminal I am getting this error

> "ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
>   (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/gmac.local.pid)."

What is PID?

How can I solve the issue with the PID?

I tried many solutions. However; none of them works

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

These kind of errors, usually can be caused by

1. Bad installation
2. Or you are using port `3306` (assuming that you are using the default mysql port) and it is used by other application.

> What is PID?

PID means `Process Id`. Each program (process) has some Id. You can kill the process using its `PID` by running in terminal

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Where `PID` is the **process Id** that you want to kill.

Probably, you are asking, how can I find the PID that I want to kill?

you can run:

```
sudo ps aux | grep application
```

Where application is the name of the application you want to kill. In this case,

`sudo ps aux | grep mysql`

It will return something like this:

```
mysql     1612  0.0  0.3 821220 27300 ?        Ssl  Jul01   0:49 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

The second string is the PID (in this case 1612) Therefore; If I want to kill mysql I have to run

```
sudo kill -9 1612
```

And Restart Mysql using XAMPP Control Panel

### Questions:

1. Have you installed another instance of XAMPP?
2. Have you installed a standalone Mysql service?
3. Have you installed MariaDB or some Database program that use port `3306`?

If answer is **YES**, you need to change the port or you have to uninstall the other installation.

I hope this works for you.