# XAMPP manager can't start server on OS X but it work on terminal

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, xampp

First my english might be bad so if you understand what I mean but the sentence is not correct feel free to edit my post, and if you don't understand I'll try my best to explain better.

I installed XAMMP on my MyBook Air version 10.11.5. I can launch the application but in "Manage servers" when I press the "Start all" button all the status switched from "Stopped" to "Starting" and then return to "Stopped" after about 20 seconds. Here is the application log :

```
Starting MySQL Database...

Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting ProFTPD...
Checking syntax of configuration file
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd started
```

Two things here : the MySQL database doesn't send anything in return and it seem that for the log the servers are running. So maybe it was only a display problem on the "Manage servers" tab so I tried to go to the adress `http://localhost` but nothing.

After a lot of research and try the only topic who gives me what I want is this one : [MySQL Database won't start in XAMPP Manager-osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267064/mysql-database-wont-start-in-xampp-manager-osx/) 
The command `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`works perfectly. So now I can start the MySQL server only. The I noticed something, here is the terminal log :

```
MacBook-Air:~ user$ sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
Starting MySQL
. SUCCESS!
```

You can see I had to enter my session password. So my questions are simple :

Could the password be the problem for the XAMPP Manager ?
i.e. the manager try to launch the servers but encounter the password request and then failed to launch the servers.

If it's the case how can I give to XAMPP the access so the manager can launch on is own the servers without needed to use the terminal ?

Is there any command like the one below to launch also the PHP server if I can't fix the Manager problem ?

I promise I did research on this topic but I find nothing about this specific password (I was often redirected on starting session password...).

Thank you for reading and maybe for answering !

Answer (score 2):

Yes because thats not the right way to start XAMPP.
You should do the following instead `cd` to your xampp application folder, there should be a executable file called xampp. The gui application is not that good, I've had various problems with it, I think the best thing to do is to start it via terminal.

The password is not the problem, its asking because it requires admin privileges to run it. Thats why you're using `sudo`.

Run the following command:

```
sudo ./xampp start
```

You can find the list of all xampp terminal commands by typing the following:

```
./xampp -h
```

For example you can start different 'modules' of the application separately e.g to start just apache.

```
sudo ./xampp startapache
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This should have help but it return "XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit compatibility library for your system.". I found some answers about this on the internet, gonna try them and post the result. Thank you anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something broken with the installer?
I had the same issue, but after downgrading to 7.0.5 everything works fine on El Capitan.