# MySQL Database on XAMPP 7.1.7 no longer working

Tags: php, mysql, macos, xampp

my MySQL Database on XAMPP 7.1.7 is not running anymore. I tried numerous solutions proposed in this post [MySQL Database won't start in XAMPP Manager-osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267064/mysql-database-wont-start-in-xampp-manager-osx) but with no luck so far. Here's what I’ve tried:

- sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start *->
  Terminal simply states „ERROR!“*
- sudo killall mysqld *-> Terminal states „No matching processes were found“*
- changing the MySQL port from 3306 to 3307 in the XAMPP Control Panel *-> no change*
- killing all active mysql processes in Monitor Activity tool *-> couldn’t find any active processes named „mysql“ or „sql“*

Clearly I don’t know what the problem and it feels I’m just randomly trying out every solution I stumple upon.

So I am posting below my log files from xamppfiles/var/mysql/[mycomputername].home.err. 
Maybe there's an indication in here of what the problem might be?

```
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ibdata1
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2018-04-02 20:05:21 140735637578560 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-04-02 20:05:21 29871 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/josephs-imac.home.pid ended
```

Any help would be highly appreciated :-)

Comment: Did you perchance delete /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ibdata1?

Comment: Yes I did try that...

Comment: This question may be better suited for https://serverfault.com/.